# Enable APFS snapshots without enabling Time Machine backups

Tags: macos, time-machine, apfs

In addition to the usual incremental backups to external media, Time Machine also automatically creates, manages, and prunes *local* APFS snapshots. These snapshots can be viewed in Time Machine's Finder-esque UI just like the incremental backups to external media. So, you can use these Time Machine snapshots to view recent versions of your file system, say to retrieve an old file that was just deleted using `rm(1)`.

It appears Time Machine will only automatically create local snapshots after it is configured to backup to external media. Is it possible to enable automatic APFS snapshots without enabling Time Machine backups to external media?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I don't want an entire Time Machine backup onto a separate disk, but I would like to have automatic local snapshots.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarcWilson I just edited to question to add a bit more context.

Comment: Do you have at least some sort of external storage? You can point Time Machine to back up to a sparse bundle, then just delete the sparse bundle. You'll then have an entry in time machine (making it "set-up"), which should enable APFS snapshots, right? I've never tried it, so I don't know if you need a first backup, though.

Comment: @At0mic I should have mentioned this in the question: I already tried the sparsebundle idea, but Time Machine won't even show it as an option. I could "set it up" with some random external disk and then never plug that disk in again (or format it), but then Time Machine would remind me every so often that I haven't backed up in a while. So, that would be a _workaround_ (that I haven't tried yet though). I'm mostly wondering whether there's a way to _directly_ enable automatic snapshots.

Comment: @Sagar you can set it to a sparsebundle with a terminal command, but if you don't want it nagging you to do a backup, it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'll mention the workaround I've employed:

1. Mount an external disk that I don't use anymore.
2. Set it up as the Time Machine disk.
3. Eject the disk, and never amount it again.
4. Profit.

Time Machine automatically creates snapshots now. This solution was not my first choice since Time Machine will remind me to mount the external disk for backup, but I haven't received that notification yet.

@At0mic mentioned in the comments that it might be possible to use a sparsebundle as the target disk, but that this needs to be done from the command line. I haven't tried this, but please edit this answer if you do.

Comment: Another possible workaround is to use ``tmutil snapshot`` to create a local snapshot manually. To automate this, a script or cron job can be used. I haven't tested if this works if Time Machine is disabled, as I have TM enabled and don't have spare hardware to test on. I stumbled upon this while trying to solve a similar issue with creating snapshots of data already stored on an external drive without requiring yet another storage device: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451418/creating-a-non-tm-snapshot-of-an-external-apfs-volume?noredirect=1#comment654536_451418

Comment: @Rafal Three months in, I'm happy to note that Time Machine is not spamming me with notifications. I think I may have been prompted once or twice, but I probably just dismissed the notification. I considered rolling my own with a cronjob, but I really wanted Time Machine to just handle everything (creating and pruning snapshots) for me.

Comment: PSA: I was able to use the workaround in this answer, but instead of using an external disk I used a sparsebundle.

Comment: (1) Create a sparsebundle using disk utility (which was then automatically mounted at /Volumes/TimeMachine - TimeMachine was the name I chose). (2) `sudo tmutil setdestination /Volumes/TimeMachine`. (3) Eject the TimeMachine volume in Finder. (4) Wait a few hours and confirm snapshots are created via `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`